# How to generate curved text?

Tags: php, gd, watermark

I am need of watermark an image with curved text. How to generate curved text?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a graphic design software like [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org/) or [Photoshop](https://www.adobe.com/products/photoshop.html), but you need to learn all the steps for creating the curved text.

You can also use a simple online tool like [MockoFun](https://www.mockofun.com/) to create [curved or circle text](https://www.mockofun.com/tutorials/curved-text-generator/).

Here's a video of how to do that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-rapX6WRL-U

The idea is to upload your image in the software, create your curved text, reduce the opacity so that the text becomes transparent and then save the image.

Alternatively, you can create the curved text, reduce its opacity and then save it as a PNG (with transparency). In this way you will have a PNG watermark image that you can reuse for adding on multiple images.